# How do I install Cloudera Hue on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue

Has anyone tried this? Google turns up a complete blank and it's been an arduous process so far (I'm pretty new to make, ant, etc).

After downloading a multitude of dependencies, some frankly unwise use of 'ln -s' and copious amounts of 'sudo'...I finally have hit an error I can't get past.

```
$ cd /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0
$ sudo make install

[snip]

--- Building Hadoop plugins
cd /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java && ant  -Dbuild.dir=/Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/build/java -Dhadoop.home=/usr/lib/hadoop -Dplugins.version=1.2.0 jar
Buildfile: /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/build.xml

init:

compile-gen:
     [echo] contrib: hue
    [javac] /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/build.xml:69: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 55 source files to /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/build/java/classes
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

compile:
     [echo] contrib: hue
     [echo] src dir: /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/java
    [javac] /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/build.xml:85: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 10 source files to /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/build/java/classes
    [javac] /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ThriftJobTrackerPlugin.java:1036: getMapCounters(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters) in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress cannot be applied to ()
    [javac]                 JTThriftUtils.toThrift(jip.getMapCounters()));
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] /Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/ThriftJobTrackerPlugin.java:1038: getReduceCounters(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Counters) in org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobInProgress cannot be applied to ()
    [javac]                 JTThriftUtils.toThrift(jip.getReduceCounters()));
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
/Users/bob/Downloads/hue-1.2.0/desktop/libs/hadoop/java/build.xml:85: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I'm on Mac OS X 10.7.2 (Lion) and running Hadoop CDH3 (hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2), Hue 1.2.0.

Any assistance would be much appreciated - many thanks in advance.

Comment: I made an attempt at it a while ago, but ran into a mess of dependencies.  I ended up using the Cloudera Linux VM instead.

Answer (score 4):

We wrote a guide about this topic: http://gethue.com/start-developing-hue-on-a-mac-in-a-few-minutes/

Answer (score 2):

The Hue release download you're trying to compile, works only until CDH3u1 onwards, after which CDH3 had some internal API method changes, over some methods that Hue depends on.

The following works for me, to compile Hue 1.2.0 against CDH3u1:

```
$ wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u1.tar.gz
$ tar xf hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u1.tar.gz; export HADOOP_HOME=hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u1
$ cd hue-1.2.0/
$ make apps
```

You'd of course need some dependencies to compile all components successfully. I use Homebrew to manage mine, and this is my currently installed list (you do not need all of these, but may need some of these):

```
$ brew list
autoconf    gd      jpeg        pango       rrdtool
automake    gettext     libffi      pidof       snappy
cairo       glib        libtool     pixman      wget
cmake       gnu-sed     lua     pkg-config  xz
coreutils   gnuplot     mysql       protobuf
expat       intltool    p7zip       readline
```

For a release of Hue that works with your CDH3 version, you can pick the right download from the CDH3 archives: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/.

So, for your CDH3u2 version, download and use http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hue-1.2.0.0-cdh3u2.tar.gz which carries 1.2.0 version of Hue with some backports on it from master that fix compilation for CDH3u2.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what version of Hue to use. I have HBase data in Ubuntu. Please recommend a Hue version and a link for download

Comment: If you recheck the response, there is such info at the end of post.